# failed to looping using if...then else

Tags: excel, vba

i write this code for commandbutton to insert the data from userform into excel worksheet. the problem is with my loop. what i want to do with the loop is when the value of `cells(i,2)` is equal to value of `strProduct(comboBox)`, i want to insert new row at the cell(i,2) then insert new data at the new created row. if value of cells(i,2) is not equal to value of strProduct, then proceed to next value of i. here's the code

```
Private Sub CmdEnter_Click()


    Dim strProduct As String
    Dim intCountData As Long

    strProduct = ComboBox1.Value
    intCountData = Worksheets("Input").Range("B31").Rows.Count


    For i = 32 To intCountData + 31

        If Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 2) <> strProduct Then
            GoTo finish1:
        Else
            Rows(i).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            ActiveCell.Insert.Cells(i, 2) = ComboBox1
            Exit Sub
        End If
    finish1:
    Next

End Sub
```

the reason why i start i=32 is because the row start at row 32.

Comment: Don't use `goto`; plus, what problem are you asking/facing?

Comment: `intCountData` will always equal 1 as the row count of a single cell will always be 1. Hence the loop reads `For i = 32 to 32` and so there is no loop to execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim strProduct As String
    Dim intCountData As Long
    strProduct = ComboBox1.Value
    lastrow = Range("a1000").End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 31 To lastrow

        If Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2) = strProduct Then
            Rows(i).Select
            Cells(i, 2) = ComboBox1.Value
            GoTo finish1
            Exit Sub
        Else
            GoTo finish1
        End If
finish1:
    Next

End Sub
```